# Unit testing of tls enabled in akka http

Tags: scala, https, akka, akka-http

I have enabled tls in my application to use HTTPS instead of HTTP. Now I want to write its unit test.

```scala
 path("Ping") {
      complete("Pong")
    }
```

```scala
Get("/Ping") ~> routes ~> check {
          status shouldEqual StatusCodes.OK
        }
```

So I expect it to be **break if request sent using http and work only if sent using https**.

I have tried many things which I found on internet.

Could anyone please help me how can I test it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akka Http [TestKit](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/testkit.html) is designed to test your route functionality and not how the route is served.

The route serving mechanism (plain text/ssl) is controlled when you bind to http port like in the following code

```scala
Http().newServerAt("127.0.0.1", 8080).enableHttps(https).bind(routes)
```

For more details refer to the [docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/server-side/server-https-support.html#using-https)

Thus, you could only test your `https` setup with the help of integration tests, where you boot your application and use a real http client and not `akka-http-testkit` to talk to your service over `https`. How to do it is outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks, This is what I was thinking that it could not be done through testkit.